Firebase phone auth not working in real Android device debugging
I'm trying to use Firebase phone authentication for my Android application developed using react-native. I have followed the below docs and completed the setup.

https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-phone-number-sign-in-for-your-firebase-project

Sign in works for me with the test number and code specified below.

But when I try to use any other phone number, I get below error.

Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.

Can anyone please help me in fixing this??  I have enabled "Google Play Integrity API" in my google cloud console as well.
Logcat logs


I fixed this problem by updated doing below 2 things

Update restrictions on my key for the firebase project from google console
It seems if we update the SHA1 fingerprint in Firebase project, it creates a new key and does not update the existing one. I updated the SHA1 manually on my key and everything worked.

